# Window.open(url) opens two times in Edge browser v42.XXX

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am opening url in window.open("XXXXXX") which is working fine(opening url only once) in IE11 and chrome v67.x.xxxx. But same is opening twice (url opens in two tabs) in Edge 42.xxx.xxx for all the time. But the same working in Edge 38.xxx.xxx.

How to overcome this or any workaround for this?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Like this - window.open(getMyURL("A"))

Comment: What does getMyURL("A") return?

Comment: getMyURL("A") return a url("https://xxxx") based on given param. All the URLs are available in window.config

Comment: Can you paste the returned value of the function getMyURL("A")?